# Repetition of the verb "to be" after let

Tags: be

If one has multiple sentences all of the form "Let x be y" written successively. Is it grammatically correct to write "and god said "let apples be red, oranges be orange, etc""?. Is it possible to not repeat the verb "to be" and to simply write "let apples be red, oranges orange, etc".

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks for your comments, I edited the question. The original phrase comes from maths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's grammatically acceptable to leave out the word "be".

This is a form of ellipsis (specifically, "gapping"). See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)#Gapping